# What Are The Steps to Evaluate the Integral $\int_{0}^{5}s\sqrt{25-s^2}$ With u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

## Summary

Forgive me. I'm brand new to integrals and I feel like we went from 0 to 100 really fast in class. I'm sure I'm missing a step somewhere or have a calculation that's off.

## Problem

Use the substitution formula to evaluate the integral:

$\int_{0}^{5}s\sqrt{25-s^2}$

### Step 1: Find u and du

$u=25-s^2$
$du=-2s\ ds$

### Step 2: Substitute

$\int (s)\sqrt{u}(du)$

### Step 3: Find anti-derivative of u

$\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}du$

### Step 4: Replace Values

$(s)(\frac{2}{3})(25-s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(-2s)\ ds$

### Step 5: Evaluate b - a. (Forget about a since a = 0)

$(5)(\frac{2}{3})(25-5^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(-2(5))\ ds$ = 0

## The Real Answer Is Different

I'm not sure where I'm off, but the provided answer in the example on my homework is $\frac{125}{3}$

### Edit 4/14/2019

With help from the answers and comments I found that I was missing a piece between steps 1 and 2. I should have been solving for $s\ ds$ which gives me $s\ ds = -\frac{1}{2}du$. I also wasn't finding my new bounds which end up being $\int_{25}^{0}$

Comment: On a quick glance, you have an error here: $u=25 - s^2 \Rightarrow du = 2s ds$. Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Forgot to make it negative. Edited. :)

Comment: The anti-derivative should not have a $du$ or $ds$ term.  Your "forget about $a$ since $a=0$" is not correct since $(25-0^2)^{3/2}$ is not $0$

Comment: Also once you have the $u^{3/2}$ part, just replace the $u$. There should be no $du$ anymore, hence no need to replace that with a $ds $. It would be good if you had some worked examples (e.g. in a textbook, or search online) of $u$substitution, so you could see how it works.

Comment: At step 2, you should have completely replaced all $s$ with $u$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth: I don't follow. Do you mean once I have $u^\frac{3}{2}$ (the reciprocal exponent from what you said)? And if so.. Is that different from what I do in Step 4?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant $u^{3/2}$.

Comment: Your only mistake is when you say "forget about $a$". Try again and see what you get.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Regarding the comment about worked examples: Yeah, that would be great to have. Unfortunately, some of the questions in the homework only provide a video link to u-subsitution in general. This is helping me realize that I'm forgetting at least 2 steps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the indefinite integral

$$\int s\sqrt{25-s^2} ds$$

Let $u = 25-s^2$ and $du = -2s\ ds$, and so

$$s\ ds = -\frac12 du$$

Substitute **both** the $25-s^2$ and $s\ ds$ in the indefinite integral:

$$\begin{align*}
\int s\sqrt{25-s^2} ds &= \int\sqrt u\left(-\frac12 du\right)\\
&= -\frac12 \int \sqrt u\ du\\
&= -\frac12\cdot\frac23u^{3/2}+C\\
&= -\frac13\left(25-s^2\right)^{3/2} + C
\end{align*}$$

For the definite integral, substitute both bounds $0$ and $5$, ignoring the $C$ which will be eliminated:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^5 s\sqrt{25-s^2} ds
&= \left[-\frac13\left(25-s^2\right)^{3/2} + C\right]_0^5\\
&= \left[-\frac13\left(25-5^2\right)^{3/2} + C\right] - \left[-\frac13\left(25-0^2\right)^{3/2} + C\right]\\
&= 0 - \left(-\frac13\right)25^{3/2}\\
&= \frac{125}3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How are you getting $s\ ds = -\frac{1}{2}du$? That looks key and I'm seeing $s\ ds = -\frac{1}{2}du^2$

Comment: @dapperdan1985 $du = -2s\ ds$, so $s\ ds = -\frac12 du$.

Comment: I see. I thought I was taking the antiderivative. My text didn't explain very well to solve for ds.

Comment: All of the answers provide immense value. I found this answer to do the best job showing where I went wrong (solving for $s\ ds$)

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've had a more detailed look.

A few things here:

1. $u = 25 - s^2$. Good choice of substitution, however your area element is not correct. $du \neq 2s ds$. **It should be $$du = -2s\hspace{1mm} ds$$** which gives $ds = -\frac{1}{2s} du$
2. Your substitution step is not quite complete either (but you are on the right track!). It should start off as $$\int_0^5s\sqrt{25-s^2} ds = \int_a^b s  \sqrt{u}\hspace{2mm} \times \hspace{2mm} \left( -\frac{1}{2s}\right) \hspace{1mm} du = -\frac{1}{2} \int_a^b \sqrt{u} \hspace{1mm} du$$

What have I done? I have replaced the part under the square root with $u$. I have then changed my area element and finally I combined the terms in $s$ and took the $-2$ outside of the integral. I think you forgot about the $-\frac{1}{2}$

**What's left?**

You need to change your limits and perform the integration.

You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Good attempt!

You *must* remember to substitute out all instances of $s$.

$$u=25-s^2 \to s=\sqrt{25-u}\text{ and } du=-2s \ ds \to ds=\frac{- \ du}{2\sqrt{25 -u}}$$

You then get:

$$\int_\alpha^\beta (\sqrt{25-u})(\sqrt{u})(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{25-u}})du$$
$$=\int_\alpha^\beta{-\frac 12\sqrt u \ du }=\bigg[-\frac13u^\frac32\bigg]_\alpha^\beta$$

Then substitute in your limits: $$\alpha = u(0)=25-0^2=25$$
$$\beta=u(5)=25-5^2=0$$

So you just have $$\bigg[-\frac13 u^\frac 32\bigg]_{25}^0$$

Comment: This is very good about showing the new bounds!